# How to use requirements.txt or similar for a pickle object

Tags: python, dependencies, pickle, data-science, devops

## Problem

How can I dump a pickle object with its own dependencies?

The pickle object is generally generated from a notebook.

I tried creating `virtualenv` for the notebook to track dependencies, however this way I don't get only the imports of the pickle object but many more that's used in other places of the application, which is fine enough but not the best solution.

## Background

### What I'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to build a MLOps flow. Quick explanation: MLOps is a buzzword that's synonymous with *DevOps for machine learning*. There are different PaaS/SaaS solutions for it offered by  different companies and they commonly solve following problems:

- Automation of creating web API's from models
- Handling requirements/dependencies
- Storing & running scripts used for model generation, model binary and data sets.

I'll skip the storage part and focus on the first two.

### How I'm trying to achieve

In my case I'm trying to set up this flow using good old TeamCity where models are pickle objects generated by sk-learn. The requirements are:

- The dependencies must be explicitly defined
- Other pickle objects (rather than sk-learn) must be supported.
- The workflow for a data scientists will look like:

  - *Data scientist* uploads the pickle model with `requirements.txt`.
  - *Data scientist* commits a definition file which look like this:

  ```
   apiPort: 8080
   apiName: name-tagger
   model: model-repository.internal/model.pickle
   requirements: model-repository.internal/model.requirements
   predicterVersion: 1.0
  ```

  - where predicter is a FLASK application with own `requirements.txt`. It's an API wrapper/layer of a pickle model that loads the model in the memory and serves predictions from a rest endpoint.

Then a build configuration in TeamCity parses the file and executes the following:

1. Parse the definition file.
2. Find the predicter code
3. Copy the pickle model as model.pickle in predicter applications root folder
4. Merge `requirements.txt` of predicter with `requirements.txt` of pickle model
5. Create virtualenv, install dependencies, push it as wheel

As output of the flow I have a package including a REST API that consumes a pickle model and exposes to the defined port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such complex build steps I use a [Makefile](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/make/) for on-prem system, and on cloud-based MLOps using something like [AWS CodeBuild with sagemaker](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop/blob/master/README.md).

An example would be as follows for packaging dependencies and executing the below build steps would require three files your **main.py** containing driver function of your code, **[Pipfile](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/basics/)** containing dependencies for your virtualenv and models:

1. **main.py**

```
def main():
      do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

2. **Pipfile**

```
[[source]]
url = 'https://pypi.python.org/simple'
verify_ssl = true
name = 'pypi'

[requires]
python_version = '2.7'

[common-packages]
scipy >= "0.17.0"
pandas 

[model1-packages]
numpy >= "1.11.0"

[model2-packages]
numpy == "1.0.0"
```

3. **Makefile**

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := run

init:
    pipenv --three install
    pipenv shell

analyze:
    flake8 ./src

run_tests:
    pytest --cov=src test/jobs/

run:

    # cleanup
    find . -name '__pycache__' | xargs rm -rf

    # run the job
    python main.py
```

After you customize these 3 files for your use case the process can be executed using the following command:

```
make run
```

Comment: Instead of just giving a link, you'd better provide some example

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I've added some generic code for your learning.